# appengine: How to query entities by key, in entities with ancester?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a problem with my app on Google AppEngine, especially with the datastore.
The story is a bit long. My data model looks like this:

1. Users can create entities. Each entity has the following properties:
   #1). the auto generated key. #2). The creator. #3). A number.
2. In the app, I'm doing the following queries:
   a). Query entities by creator (#2). b). Query entities by the number property (#3). c). Query the entity by id(#1).

I'm using the low level datastore API. Now, here are several problematic approaches I have tried:

[Approach 1]: With the Datastore, if I make the entities parentless (no ancester), then things are good, especially the query 'c' can be easily achieved by Datastore.get(k).

Problem of Approach1: Since the datastore is "eventually consistent", for query 'a' the result is ALWAYS not update to date. If a user creates an entity, then lists all entities he creates, the newly created one is always missing. It only appears by refresh in a few seconds later...Tried using memcache, does not help the case (or I'm not finding a good way?).

To overcome the problem above, I changed the data structure. Here's [Approach 2]: when creating each entity, create a key based on the creator, and put the new entity as child of the key. So all entities created by a user are entities with an ancester. Thus query 'a' works in a timely manner, and query 'b' also seems to work.

The new problem of Approach2: For query 'c', it always returns nothing. Here's my query 'c'. Both of them can not find the entity, always:

method 1:
    Entity en = datastore.get(k)

method2:

```
DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query(kind)
    .setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, k));
Entity en = ds.prepare(q).asSingleEntity();
```

Another try: Approach3:
Group all entities under one ancestor. This overcomes the problem in Approach1, and can be queried with an ancestor filter so it's ok to retrieve the result.

Problem of Approach3: Such structure groups all entities as one entity group. Per Google datastore specification, write operation can happen 5 times at the most per second. This is a limit I'd not want to hit...

I think this kind of data model is really common. Is there a proper way to structure the data? Any help is appreciated. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking due to the formatting of your question but...

When you query by ID you also have to include the parent key. The key includes both the parents and the child data, and if you are only using the child data then it won't return what you are looking for as that's not it's "name". The full path (ancestor/child) is it's name.

So include the parent in the key you are constructing, then get it.

```
key = parent, parent_ID, child, child_ID
```

as

```
key = child, ID
```

won't work if it has a parent, as the key is incomplete and it can't return the data you want like that.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the answer. As in Approach 2, entities are grouped under different ancestors, so there's no such one-for-all path for all the entities I want to query. If the entities are created without ancestor, then the query works fine but it's always not update to date (fall back to Approach 1).

Comment: Actually there's another Approach 3: group all of the entities in one ancestor. It resolves the problem in Approach 1, and can be queried like Paul mentioned. But it has a new problem: per Google datastore specification, entities under one ancestor are considered as "one entity group", and there's a limit for write operation on entities in "one entity group": only 5 per second at the most. This is another limit I would not want to hit...

Comment: on the up to date issue, what I intend to do about that when it becomes a problem for me is to explicitly write the content into memcache and then try and retrieve it from there firstly, only falling back to the datastore if that fails. You say that does not work for you, but I can't see why. If you have a function that returns data but where it returns it from is transparent (i.e. it tries memcache then falls back to datastore if none) then can't see how it could not work for you. In general I do this anyway by default as I can always invalidate memcache when I write new data explicitly.

Comment: Restructured the memcache stuff to cache both "list of user entity ids" and "recent entities". It works now. Thanks!

Comment: great! And that'll save you lots of $$ too in the long run. plus have a look at NDB if you are not already using it as it has lots of in built caching automatically applied. queries are not cached however!